# TIcketmaster API? Buy tickets within website?

Tags: api

I have done some googling am information is scarce. Is there a way to use ticketmaster within a website to allow users to buy tickets within a site? If ticketmaster isn't avaliable is there another service?

Answer (score 7):

Ticketmaster doesn't have a public API (there is a private API that you can access with their permission if you're an official partner of Ticketmaster).

Here's a list of public ticketing APIs: https://www.programmableweb.com/apitag/tickets+events

Comment: i want an api from Ticket mastser either free or paid that will respond that ticket is valid or not, actually idea is that from barcode scanner user will scan of their ticket generated by ticket master, and after scanning result would be either valid or invalid, please suggest how your api will work for me.

Comment: Dont think they have that yet. Might probably be released later this year @RamS

Comment: This answer is now out of date. The developer portal is hosted at http://developer.ticketmaster.com/

Answer (score 4):

Just attended the devjam hosted by them and there is a public API now but the transactions api is still not public yet

http://ticketmaster-api.github.io/

Hope they make is available soon

Comment: Neat! Are they going to support transactions via api by sending credit card. That would be pretty great for the ecosystem

Answer (score 3):

Check out http://developer.ticketmaster.com/

Now with commerce API, as well as Discovery, Event Offers, Partner, Deals, Publish and International Discovery.

Answer (score 1):

I was also searching same kind of things, and yet found only API to fetch events from ticketmaster and via deep_url etc i can redirect my client to ticketmaster website for ticket purchasing, I also tried to do so that one can purchase tickets directly from my website but i amm not successfull yet.

Moreover there ticket fetching API also dont have any information regarding tickets and its purchase.
link of ticket fetch api documentation is https://darwin.affiliatewindow.com/documents/ticketmaster/Ticketmaster%20API.pdf